# Why are there symbols in my code?

Tags: node.js, meteor, vue.js

I'm am using MeteorJS and VueJs. When the code gets compiled I get som ugly bundled stuff.

[image]

The module that I am trying to include is something that i made up myself. 
I am including the module like this

```
import * as fun from 'azure-image-upload';
Vue.use(fun);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like it's related to encoding. Is the code / app running or any errors / malfunctions?

Comment: Yes, errors. Nothing works at all. The bundle file i messed up because of these few lines of code.

Comment: can you please add the code of the original file and the errors that occured on console`?

Comment: Are you sure the encoding of those js files matches the encoding of the page (UTF-8 being the default in Meteor)?